# How to validate in routes (Lumen)

Tags: laravel, lumen

Validation does work if I don't use:

```
'uses' => 'ArticleController@talentPagination']
```

Working:

```
$router->get('/api/talents/{id:[0-9]+}/articles', [function (Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'per_page'     => 'Required|integer|min:1',
        'page'         => 'Required|integer|min:1',
        'published_at' => 'Required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'
    ]);
});
```

But, how can I specify Controller and action after it passes the validation?

I tried to use 'uses' but it skips the validation, like:

```
$router->get('/api/talents/{id:[0-9]+}/articles', [function (Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'per_page'     => 'Required|integer|min:1',
        'page'         => 'Required|integer|min:1',
        'published_at' => 'Required|date_format:Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z'
    ]);
}, 'uses' => 'ArticleController@talentPagination']);
```

Is there a way I can validate it and then route it to the controller action?

```
Lumen ver: 5.6
Php: 7.1.9
```

Comment: Sounds like you're wanting to use a `middleware`

Comment: @Derek thank you, gonna check it out.